# SyntaxError: Use of const in strict mode in package loaded with Meteor.npmRequire

Tags: meteor, npm, require, strict-mode

I have a Meteor app that requires an NPM package via `Meteor.npmRequire` that is provided by `meteorhacks:npm` package. The problem is that this package uses latest ES6 features and `npmRequire` doesn't, so what I get is

```
Exception while invoking method 'fetchSomething' SyntaxError: Use of const in strict mode.
(STDERR) 
(STDERR) /Users/rishatmuhametshin/bankathon/controller/packages/npm-container/.npm/package/node
(STDERR) const Stringify = require('./stringify');
(STDERR) ^^^^^
```

How do I override this behavior? Is it possible to make `Meteor.npmRequire` respect ES6 features instead of sticking to ES5 strict mode?

Comment: having something similar , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39794780/ionic2-white-screen-error-on-deploy-android-4-2-2-use-of-const-in-strict-mode .. any news?