# Ionic2 White screen error on deploy Android 4.2.2: Use of const in strict mode

Tags: android, meteor, angular, ecmascript-6, ionic2

i can deploy to a real device and to a emulator using `Android` **4.1.1**, **4.2.2**, **4.4.2**.

But it always shows a *white* screen and in the console I can see the error `Uncaught SyntaxError Use of const in strict mode.`

[This](https://github.com/mariohmol/brigadistas) is project and my system info is:

```
Cordova CLI: You have been opted out of telemetry. To change this, run: cordova telemetry on.
6.3.1

Gulp version: CLI version 3.9.1
Gulp local: Local version 3.9.1

Ionic Framework Version: 2.0.0-beta.11
Ionic CLI Version: 2.1.0
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.1.0-beta.1
ios-deploy version: 1.4.0
ios-sim version: 3.1.1
OS: Mac OS X El Capitan
Node Version: v6.3.1
Xcode version: Xcode 7.3.1 Build version 7D1014
```

- https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/issues/8328

Comment: You have to use babel to compile down. Currently I don't know any solution to this but the idea is to add babel to webpack

Comment: thanks!! i had the same idea.. but looks like that they made a different solution using the browser plugin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could make that work!! =)

For those who get here:

- ionic platform add browser
- ionic build browser
- ionic plugin add cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview
- Remove the old app from the device
- ionic build
- ionic run android

As we are talking about old mobiles, dont forget you have that in your config.xml

`<preference name="loadUrlTimeoutValue" value="60000" />`