# 'Use of const in strict mode': How can `node_modules/[sub_folder]` can compile to ES5 and not ES6?

Tags: ecmascript-6, ionic3, ecmascript-5, gsap

Config from `ionic info`:

`Cordova CLI: 8.0.0
Ionic Framework Version: 3.9.2
Ionic CLI Version: 2.2.3
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.2.1
Ionic App Scripts Version: 3.2.0
Node Version: v6.14.4`

Working on some update on an Ionic 2 project previously running on an Android 4.4 device.

I ran in an error similar to this one: [Ionic2 White screen error on deploy Android 4.2.2: Use of const in strict mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39794780/ionic2-white-screen-error-on-deploy-android-4-2-2-use-of-const-in-strict-mode)

After research I found that under my project in `[project]/android/app/src/main/www/assets/build/vendor.js` I have some `const` used to define variables in the file.

Variables marked with `const` seem to be all linked to directory `node_module/gsap` ([this library](https://greensock.com/gsap)).

My understanding is that `gsap` generate in **`ES6` format instead of `ES5` format** in the `vendor.js` file.

The GSAP version is 1.20.6.

Internet reading made me understood that through `webpack` or `babel` I could control that it generates in `ES5` format.

But I don't understand how to do that in `[project]/tsconfig.json` file where it is stated:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    ...
    "target": "es5",
    ...
  }
  "exclude": ["node_modules"],
   ...
}
```

Do you have an idea how to force ES5 in a defined sub `node_modules` directory like `node_modules/gsap`

Answer (score 0):

Downgrading to gsap~1.19.1 helped to do a workaround to this problem.